# rebase and merge in a submodule do not work as expected

Tags: git

I have a git repository with a submodule, let's say `somelib`.

I rebased my working branch of `somelib` to `development` branch and did some merges

```
git rebase development
git pull
```

after that I expected that

```
git status
```

from the root repository will display `somelib` submodule in red color with (new commits) message, but it did not.

How is it possible?

What is the difference between adding a commit to `somelib`, for example, and doing rebase+merge?

**EDIT1**

```
git submodule status
```

displays that the root repository points to the latest commit of my working branch in `somelib`.

Answer (score 1):

If the submodule is set to a different commit than the one *recorded* in the root repository or there are uncommitted changes, you have to see the following when doing a `git status` in the root repository:

`modified:   somelib (modified content)` or  `modified:   somelib (new commits)`

If you do not see this, it means that what you think happened did not.

When doing `git rebase development`, you rebase somelib over the *local* development branch. Did you mean to rebase on the *remote* development branch instead? If so, you need to do (assuming the remote is called *origin*):

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/development
```

Then, you do not need to do `git pull` as all the modifications on the remote branch should now be integrated into the current checked out branch in the somelib submodule.

Now, if the branch checked out in somelib points to the same commit as the development branch, you won't have modified anything and doing `git status` in the root repository won't show anything regarding somelib.